# echo jquery data table select query in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery

I want to echo this select query of jquery data table.
I the use codeigniter framework.

Below is my code.

```
 $this->datatables->select("@a:=@a+1 serial_number, id as staff_id, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)as staff_name, email,phone_number,department", false);
    $this->datatables->from("staff_member, (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a");
    $this->datatables->where('status', '1');
    ## Email condition

    if (isset($_POST['sSearch']) && $_POST['sSearch'] != '') {
        $this->datatables->like('first_name', trim($_POST['sSearch']), 'both');
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') {
        $this->datatables->like('email', trim($_POST['email']), 'both');
    }
    mprd($this->datatables->generate());    
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: you have to provide your database functions as well...

Comment: simple I want to echo this query.

Comment: @jigsVirani you will have to find in its classes that where it is executing the query... so you can use `echo` just before the query is getting executed in your class file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this.Simply echo last executed query.

```
     echo $this->datatables->generate();
     echo $this->db->last_query();
```